# Android：Activity is blocking with black screen when it occur Exception

Tags: java, android

If my codes have errors, the `Activity` is blocked with black screen. But it doesn't throw any `exception`, only single line word in `Android Monitor`.

```
11-09 17:03:03.984 14252-14262/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC HeapTrim
11-09 17:03:03.986 14252-14258/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
```

In this `Activity`,all `exception` has not been thrown. Can Someone tell me why?

Comment: can you post the code where you think exception is thrown?

Comment: you have to look into logcat for error stacktrace (remove the filters also)...

Comment: All exception didn't been thrown, i didn't write while(ture)....

Answer (score 1):

I caught exception by myself。

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    }
}
```